# Hidden redirect http to https with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https

I need to redirect a http page to a https and make it hidden, like:

http://www.example1.com -> https://www.example2.com

So example1 is always visible in the URL bar, and example2 is hidden.

Will something like this work? If not, what should I change?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.html
RewriteRule ^index.html https://www.example2.com [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at these two articles, they seem to have your answer. :)

http://joseph.randomnetworks.com/2004/07/22/redirect-to-ssl-using-apaches-htaccess/

https://serverfault.com/questions/116206/how-do-i-use-htaccess-to-always-redirect-from-http-to-https